# what is the best way to escape two character escape sequences in an ANTLR4 grammar?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am trying to write an ANTLR4 parser for a templating language similar to mustache. This uses `{{...}}` tags interspersed in a normal text file. If the template needs to contain and emit `{` next to an OPEN_TAG `{{`, there can be a problem with the lexer/parser. I believe there should be a way to write the parser such that:

`This is a left brace {{{tag logic}} and here are two left braces {{{tag logic}}{`

translates to

`This is a left brace { and here are two left braces {{`

Either:

1. How can I tell the lexer to only match OPEN_TAG to `{{` followed by
   anything but `{`, absorbing the leading `{`s into the previous TEXT
   pattern?
2. Is there a "better" way to provide an escape sequence for `{{`?

Thanks!

Comment: I see that you don't ask many questions on the SO site, but given that you do post answers: please do not forget to followup on your questions and either comment or accept if they meet your criteria. Asking questions and giving answers are rather separate skills, as I've noticed myself as well :|

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica you're right, i'm sorry.  honestly i'm fairly novice at asking questions on SO... like you said I actually enjoyed answering questions more.  didn't even realize i was leaving people hanging.  i'll try to rectify this where i've dropped the ball.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the tags in the lexer using a mode.

```
LBrace   : '{' ;
RBrace   : '}' ;
TOpenTag  : '{{' -> pushMode(tagLogic) ;


mode tagLogic ;

TLBrace   : '{' -> type(LBrace) ;
TRBrace   : '}' -> type(RBrace) ;
TCloseTag : '}}' -> popMode     ;
TLogic    : [a-zA-Z0-9]+        ;
TWs       : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip  ;
```